# Express http only working with localhost but not with external ip http connection

Tags: node.js, express

Tried to avoid the listen IP only on the '127.0.0.1', so the listen port 8000 is also bind with the '0.0.0.0'. But external http clients still not able to get the http connection setup. Also tried tcpdump, the client SYN can reach to the node server, but not any response from the node.js http server... this caused the issue. Really appreciate your assistance!

```
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8000                0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      1650/node
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:56064             127.0.0.1:27017             ESTABLISHED 1650/node
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:56062             127.0.0.1:27017             ESTABLISHED 1650/node
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:56065             127.0.0.1:27017             ESTABLISHED 1650/node
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:56063             127.0.0.1:27017             ESTABLISHED 1650/node
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:56061             127.0.0.1:27017             ESTABLISHED 1650/node
```

Comment: Here is the code: [link](https://github.com/Simon-Li/schoolsearch.git)

Comment: Do you have your firewall set up appropriately to allow traffic in and out of that port?

Comment: the FW in/out rules all checked, not issues at all.